# Jekyll blog - How to show a list of posts if list file exists

Tags: jekyll, blogs

What I'm trying to do is for each category page, if a file exists with the category name then use that file for the list of popular posts. If not then I want to use the default popular posts.

The category featured post file would exist in this folder, if there is one "_includes/blog/feat-posts."

I want to display in the sidebar of my blog. Here's the code I tried using some documentation I found online. This does not work.

```
<h3>POPULAR POSTS</h3>
{% comment %}(Not sure if this is the correct code, but looking for static file){% endcomment %}
{% for static_file in site.static_files %}
  {% comment %}(if a file exists with the same name as the category name, then..){% endcomment %}
  {% if static_file.path == '_includes/blog/feat-posts/{{page.autopages.display_name}}.html' %} 
    {% comment %}(include that file){% endcomment %}
    {% include {{ blog/feat-posts/{{page.autopages.display_name}}.html }} %} 
  {% else %} 
    {% comment %}(otherwise use the default files){% endcomment %}
    <p><a href="{{site.baseurl}}/blog/filename1">Filename1 Text</a></p>
    <p><a href="{{site.baseurl}}/blog/filename2">Filename2 Text</a></p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Please help.

Comment: What exactly happens and what do you expect? Hard to tell you what's the solution. What paths are included in static_file.path? What is _includes/blog/feat-posts/{{page.autopages.display_name}}.html? Have you tested with an ordinary string? Maybe your complete code could help to see the issue/solution.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is for each category page, if a file exists with the category name then use that file for the list of popular posts If not then I want to use the default popular posts. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what "it does not work" means but I assume the error happens in the line with include or your file is not in your static_sites.

You can check the site.static_files content by adding `{{ site.static_files | inspect }}` to your code. Static files are kind of special, see https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/.

To construct paths dynamically, you may want to use `assign` to assign the value to a variable first (see simplified example below).

I could check the path by adding a file to the root folder (path /test.html) and then link to the same file name in the _includes folder:

```
<h3>POPULAR POSTS</h3>
{% comment %}{{ site.static_files | inspect }}{% endcomment %}
{% for static_file in site.static_files %}
  {% if static_file.path == '/test.html' %}
    {% assign filename = 'test.html' %}
    {% include {{ filename }} %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this helps.